# Mongodb Query to CSV dump (mlab hosted mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, export-to-csv, linear-regression, mlab

I am querying an already populated mlab MongoDB database, and I want to store the resulting multiple documents in one single CSV file.

EDIT: output format of CSV file I hope to get:

```
uniqueid        status    date 
191b117fcf5c    0         2017-03-01 15:26:28.217000
191b117fcf5c    1         2017-03-01 18:26:28.217000
```

MongoDB database document format is

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58b6bcc00bd666355805a3ee"
    },
    "sensordata": {
        "operation": "chgstatus",
        "user": {
            "status": "1",
            "uniqueid": "191b117fcf5c"
        }
    },
    "created_date": {
        "date": "2017-03-01 17:51:17.216000"
    }
}
```

Database name:mparking_sensor
collection name: demo

The python code to query is as follows:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Mar 01 18:55:18 2017

@author: Being_Rohit
"""

    import pymongo
    uri = 'mongodb://#####:*****@ds157529.mlab.com:57529/mparking_sensor'

    client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
    db = client.get_default_database().demo
    print db
    results = db.find()

    f = open("mytest.csv", "w")

    for record in results:
        query1 =  (record["sensordata"]["user"],record["created_date"])
        print query1
    print "done"
    client.close()
```

EDIT: output format of query1 I am getting is:

```
({u'status': u'0', u'uniqueid': u'191b117fcf5c'}, {u'date': u'2017-03-01 17:51:08.263000'})
```

Does someone know the correct way to dump this data in a .csv file (pandas/or any other means) or some other approach for further prediction based analysis to do on it in future like linear regression?

Comment: The data in MongoDB, which is structured JSON, does not map straightforwardly to tabular data like CSV. Can you [edit] your question to show an example of the data format you are trying to output?

Comment: Hi , could you give me some insight further?

Answer (score 1):

[Mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) will do the job for you. It can, uniquely among native MongoDB tools, export in [CSV format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#export-in-csv-format), limited to a specific set of fields.

Your mongoexport command would be something like this:

```
mongoexport.exe \
--db mparking_sensor \
--collection demo \
--type=csv \
--fields sensordata.user.uniqueid,sensordata.user.status,created_date
```

That will export something like the following:

```
sensordata.user.uniqueid,sensordata.user.status,created_date 
191b117fcf5c,0,2017-03-01T15:26:28.217000Z
191b117fcf5c,1,2017-03-01T18:26:28.217000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to export a collection to csv using mlabs 'export collection' they make it harder than it needs to be. So i used https://studio3t.com and connected using the standard MongoDB URI